# How to add additional and separated column in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to add a new column to an array to get the following shape. I tried the np.hstack function, but the cols should be separated.
Just an example, i have this arrays:

```
X = np.array([[1.,0.,0.],
              [0.,1.,0.],
              [0.,0.,1.],
              [0.,0.,0.]])
Y = np.array([[1.],
              [2.],
              [3.],
              [4.]])
```

And i need this:

```
Z = np.array([[[1.,0.,0.],[1.]],
              [[0.,1.,0.],[2.]],
              [[0.,0.,1.],[3.]],
              [[0.,0.,0.],[4.]]])
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You know that all the elements in `Z` that you have given will be references lists, and not numpy dtypes?

Comment: Yes, that was my fault. They should be numpy arrays too.

Comment: How do you intend to use `Z`?  The object array may look right, but might not be the best for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a object `dtype`, because what you need is not a actual ndarray:

```
Z=np.empty((4,2),dtype=object)
Z[:,0]=list(X)
Z[:,1]=list(Y)
```

Then Z is :

```
array([[array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.])],
       [array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 2.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]), array([ 3.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 4.])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `zip`

```
Z  = np.array(zip(X,Y))
```

This will set z as foolows

```
array([[array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.])],
       [array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 2.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]), array([ 3.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 4.])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

A structured array approach:

```
In [29]: Z=np.empty(X.shape[0],dtype=[('X','f',(X.shape[1],)),('Y','f',(Y.shape[1],))])

In [30]: Z
Out[30]: 
array([([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0]), ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0]),
       ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0]), ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0])], 
      dtype=[('X', '<f4', (3,)), ('Y', '<f4', (1,))])

In [31]: Z['X']=X

In [32]: Z['Y']=Y

In [33]: Z
Out[33]: 
array([([1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0]), ([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [2.0]),
       ([0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [3.0]), ([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [4.0])], 
      dtype=[('X', '<f4', (3,)), ('Y', '<f4', (1,))])

In [34]: Z['X']
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
In [35]: Z[1]
Out[35]: ([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [2.0])
```

Contrast with the access for the object array

```
In [40]: np.array(list(zip(X,Y)))
Out[40]: 
array([[array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.])],
       [array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 2.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]), array([ 3.])],
       [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 4.])]], dtype=object)

In [41]: W=np.array(list(zip(X,Y)))

In [42]: W[0]
Out[42]: array([array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 1.])], dtype=object)

In [43]: W[:,0]
Out[43]: 
array([array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  0.]),
       array([ 0.,  0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])], dtype=object)
```

Or you could just use `alist = [X,Y]`.